# Receive XML Through HTTP POST In ASP.NET Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, http

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application in Visual Studio and need to be able to receive XML through HTTP POST.  What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Data coming to your controler via HTTP POST is read from

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream
```

You can read it into a string using StreamReader's ReadToEnd method.

Since it is xml as specified in the title, if you want to load it into an XDocument you should read it into a byte array and create a MemoryStream from that byte array to use in the Load method of XDocument.

Example:

```
var message = XDocument.Load(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd()));
```

Gives you an XDocument containing the xml that was POSTed.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a xmlvalueproviderfactory

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class XmlValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{
    private static void AddToBackingStore(Dictionary<string, object> backingStore, string prefix, XElement xmlDoc)
    {
        // Check the keys to see if this is an array or an object
        var uniqueKeys = new List<String>();
        int totalCount = 0;
        foreach (XElement element in xmlDoc.Elements())
        {
            if(!uniqueKeys.Contains(element.Name.LocalName)) {
                uniqueKeys.Add(element.Name.LocalName);
            }
            totalCount++;
        }

        bool isArray;
        if (uniqueKeys.Count == 1) {
            isArray = true;
        }
        else if (uniqueKeys.Count == totalCount) {
            isArray = false;
        }
        else {
            // Not sure how to deal with a XML doc that has some keys the same, but not all
            // For now don't process this node
            return;
        }

        // Add the elements to the backing store
        int elementCount = 0;
        foreach (XElement element in xmlDoc.Elements())
        {
            if (element.HasElements)
            {
                if (isArray)
                {
                    // Omit local name for arrays and add index instead
                    AddToBackingStore(backingStore, String.Format("{0}[{1}]", prefix, elementCount), element);
                }
                else
                {
                    AddToBackingStore(backingStore, MakePropertyKey(prefix, element.Name.LocalName), element);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                backingStore.Add(MakePropertyKey(prefix, element.Name.LocalName), element.Value);
            }

            elementCount++;
        }
    }

    private static XDocument GetDeserializedXml(ControllerContext controllerContext) {
        var contentType = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        if (!contentType.StartsWith("text/xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            && !contentType.StartsWith("application/xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            // Are there any other XML mime types that are used? (Add them here)

            // not XML request
            return null;
        }


        XDocument xml;
        try
        {
            // DTD processing disabled to stop XML bomb attack - if you require DTD processing, read this first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335713.aspx
            var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit };
            var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream, xmlReaderSettings);
            xml = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }


        if (xml.FirstNode == null)
        {
            // No XML data
            return null;
        }

        return xml;
    }

    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) {
        XDocument xmlData = GetDeserializedXml(controllerContext);
        if (xmlData == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Dictionary<string, object> backingStore = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        AddToBackingStore(backingStore, String.Empty, xmlData.Root);
        return new DictionaryValueProvider<object>(backingStore, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    private static string MakeArrayKey(string prefix, int index) {
        return prefix + "[" + index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "]";
    }

    private static string MakePropertyKey(string prefix, string propertyName) {
        return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix)) ? propertyName : prefix + "." + propertyName;
    }
}
```

And then in your application start, call

```
  ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new XmlValueProviderFactory());
```